# Using the TextHeader and TextBody property to define the view

Tags: powershell, view

I've been tasked to create a Powershell script that will create the following view which works currently within Microsoft SQL Studio.  I've made a copy of the working script and would like to to apply it to this Microsoft example.  My question is - can you take the known working query below and insert it in the TextBody property below?

```
# Set the TextHeader and TextBody property to define the view.   
$myview.TextHeader = "CREATE VIEW [Sales].[Test_View] AS"  
$myview.TextBody ="SELECT h.SalesOrderID, d.OrderQty FROM 
Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS h INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS d ON 
h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID"  



CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PROV] AS
SELECT drname.dr_id, drname.create_dt, dr_fname, dr_iname, dr_lname, 
drtitle, drsuffix, gender, birthdate, marital, ethnic, drname.email, 
org_name, dr_ofname, dr_oiname, dr_olname, nationalid, drname.medicare, 
drname.medicaid,

CASE
               WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM stfstatu act WHERE act.dr_id = 
drname.dr_id AND fac_cd  NOT IN('SMC','WAR','CCS') AND act.active123 IN 
('1','3','N','G','6','S','U','CA','TPRO')) THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END  as Active_Status, 
              a.sch_type as Addr_Type_sch_type, a.addr, a.addr2, a.city, 
a.state, a.zip, a.phone, a.fax, a2.tax_id,
              (select top 1 rtrim(d.dr_lname) from drname d join address aa 
on d.dr_id = aa.dr_id join address2 aa2 on aa.link = aa2.l_address where 
d.verfac = 1 and aa2.tax_id = a2.tax_id and drname.verfac = 0) as 
Addr_DrPGp,
              lan_tab.txt as lan_tab_txt, dr_lan.lan_cd as dr_lan_cd, CASE 
WHEN dr_spec.specorder = 1 THEN dr_spec.specialty ELSE '' END as dr_spec, 
CASE WHEN dr_spec.PrimSpec = 1 THEN 'P' ELSE '' END as PrimSpec, school.cd 
as school_cd, school.txt as school_txt, educate.fdate as educate_fdate, 
educate.sch_type, educ_arr.txt as school_type_txt,  educate.degree, 
educ_tab.txt 
as degree_txt, educate.tdate as educate_tdate, CASE WHEN dr_spec.specorder = 
1 
THEN spec_tab.txt ELSE '' END as spec_Tab_txt,  

                  CASE WHEN stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'B' then 'Yes' WHEN 
stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'P' then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as PCP, 

              case when stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'B' then 'PCP and Specialist'
      else case when stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'P' then 'PCP'
                      else case when stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'S' then 
'Specialist'
                                       else ''
                               END
                  END
                              END as PCPSpec, taxonomy.cd as tax_cd

FROM drname
JOIN stfstatu on drname.dr_id = stfstatu.dr_id
LEFT JOIN address1 a on drname.dr_id = a.dr_id AND a.sch_type = 'G' AND 
a.link = (SELECT TOP 1 link FROM address1 WHERE sch_type = 'G' AND 
address1.dr_id = drname.dr_id ORDER BY LINK DESC)
LEFT JOIN address2 a2 on a2.l_address = a.link
LEFT JOIN dr_lan on drname.dr_id = dr_lan.dr_id
LEFT JOIN lan_tab on lan_tab.cd = dr_lan.lan_cd
LEFT JOIN dr_spec on drname.dr_id = dr_spec.dr_id
LEFT JOIN spec_tab on dr_spec.specialty = spec_tab.cd
LEFT JOIN educate on educate.dr_id = drname.dr_id
LEFT JOIN school on educate.cd = school.cd
LEFT JOIN educ_arr on educ_arr.cd = educate.sch_type
LEFT JOIN facility on facility.fac_cd = educate.fac_cd
LEFT JOIN educ_tab on educate.degree = educ_tab.cd
LEFT JOIN taxonomy on taxonomy.dr_id = drname.dr_id
--Where LTRIM(RTRIM(dr_spec.Fac_Cd)) = ''
```

Comment: NOTE: the query in the TextBody property is an example that I copied from a Microsoft site.  I'm trying to understand if you can insert a more complex working query that has CASE statements into this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try using the *here string* (https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/windows-powershell-cookbook/9780596528492/ch05s03.html]) for `TextBody`?

```
# Set the TextHeader and TextBody property to define the view.   
$myview.TextHeader = "CREATE VIEW [Sales].[Test_View] AS"  
$myview.TextBody = @"
SELECT h.SalesOrderID, d.OrderQty FROM 
Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS h INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS d ON 
h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID   

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PROV] AS
SELECT drname.dr_id, drname.create_dt, dr_fname, dr_iname, dr_lname, 
drtitle, drsuffix, gender, birthdate, marital, ethnic, drname.email, 
org_name, dr_ofname, dr_oiname, dr_olname, nationalid, drname.medicare, 
drname.medicaid,

CASE
               WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM stfstatu act WHERE act.dr_id = 
drname.dr_id AND fac_cd  NOT IN('SMC','WAR','CCS') AND act.active123 IN 
('1','3','N','G','6','S','U','CA','TPRO')) THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END  as Active_Status, 
              a.sch_type as Addr_Type_sch_type, a.addr, a.addr2, a.city, 
a.state, a.zip, a.phone, a.fax, a2.tax_id,
              (select top 1 rtrim(d.dr_lname) from drname d join address aa 
on d.dr_id = aa.dr_id join address2 aa2 on aa.link = aa2.l_address where 
d.verfac = 1 and aa2.tax_id = a2.tax_id and drname.verfac = 0) as 
Addr_DrPGp,
              lan_tab.txt as lan_tab_txt, dr_lan.lan_cd as dr_lan_cd, CASE 
WHEN dr_spec.specorder = 1 THEN dr_spec.specialty ELSE '' END as dr_spec, 
CASE WHEN dr_spec.PrimSpec = 1 THEN 'P' ELSE '' END as PrimSpec, school.cd 
as school_cd, school.txt as school_txt, educate.fdate as educate_fdate, 
educate.sch_type, educ_arr.txt as school_type_txt,  educate.degree, 
educ_tab.txt 
as degree_txt, educate.tdate as educate_tdate, CASE WHEN dr_spec.specorder = 
1 
THEN spec_tab.txt ELSE '' END as spec_Tab_txt,  

                  CASE WHEN stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'B' then 'Yes' WHEN 
stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'P' then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as PCP, 

              case when stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'B' then 'PCP and Specialist'
      else case when stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'P' then 'PCP'
                      else case when stfstatu.pcp_spec = 'S' then 
'Specialist'
                                       else ''
                               END
                  END
                              END as PCPSpec, taxonomy.cd as tax_cd

FROM drname
JOIN stfstatu on drname.dr_id = stfstatu.dr_id
LEFT JOIN address1 a on drname.dr_id = a.dr_id AND a.sch_type = 'G' AND 
a.link = (SELECT TOP 1 link FROM address1 WHERE sch_type = 'G' AND 
address1.dr_id = drname.dr_id ORDER BY LINK DESC)
LEFT JOIN address2 a2 on a2.l_address = a.link
LEFT JOIN dr_lan on drname.dr_id = dr_lan.dr_id
LEFT JOIN lan_tab on lan_tab.cd = dr_lan.lan_cd
LEFT JOIN dr_spec on drname.dr_id = dr_spec.dr_id
LEFT JOIN spec_tab on dr_spec.specialty = spec_tab.cd
LEFT JOIN educate on educate.dr_id = drname.dr_id
LEFT JOIN school on educate.cd = school.cd
LEFT JOIN educ_arr on educ_arr.cd = educate.sch_type
LEFT JOIN facility on facility.fac_cd = educate.fac_cd
LEFT JOIN educ_tab on educate.degree = educ_tab.cd
LEFT JOIN taxonomy on taxonomy.dr_id = drname.dr_id
--Where LTRIM(RTRIM(dr_spec.Fac_Cd)) = ''
"@
```